# How to update data (dom) from polymer element using vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have the follow polymer element:

```
<acre-faq id="faq"></acre-faq>
```

[image]

With the following data:

```
var seedElement = document.querySelector('#faq');
seedElement.questions = [{votes: number, question: string, 
               answers: [{answer: string, author: string, date: string}]}]
```

And when the user click on the vote event I wanna change the data from the item clicked:

```
 seedElement.addEventListener("acre-faq-up",function(e){
             e.detail.item.votes = e.detail.item.votes+1;
         });
```

But the DOM is not updated, there is a way to do this without using another polymer element to manipulate the data?

the element code: http://pastebin.com/g27DiWuE

Comment: Shouldn't you use the click event like this:  `seedElement.addEventListener("click",function(e){...}`?

Comment: the problem is not the event, the `acre-faq-up`event works and return the property data, the problem is there when I update the vote `e.detail.item.votes = e.detail.item.votes+1;` the dom is not updated

Comment: Post the `detail.item` element please

Comment: is the template of the polymer element available anywhere, as there are two possible solutions, however they depend on the way the properties have been bound in the template?

Comment: The code to create the element is here: http://pastebin.com/g27DiWuE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change data your Polymer elements bind to you need to use Polymer API for Polymer to recognize the change, like

```
set('prop.val.subval', newVal);
```

See also https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path